# Open and write files in Android NDK

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface, fopen

Why can't I open files in writing mode in C? I surely have all permisions, and the path is correct because it can be open in read mode. For example:

`file = fopen(path, "r");` returns a correct file, but 
`file = fopen(path, "w");` always return null

In the Java part I can write the file, so, the solution I found is write the data in a C array and return it to Java

I see that in other questions or programs people can write in C... is a problem of new Android versions?

Comment: What is the value of path?

Comment: I try with various paths like generated by Context.getFilesDir() or Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC). I also try to hardcode the path indicated in the file manager of my device like "/storage/emulated/0/etc"

Comment: And with java you can write using all mentioned paths?

Comment: yes, in can in java

Comment: What is the reason for a failure (try `perror`)?.

Comment: fopen() haven't failure, only returns a null pointer. Logically, if use it in fwrite() have Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Comment: [`On error, returns a null pointer. POSIX requires that errno is set in this case.`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) I suggest you try user58697's suggestion.